# ImmutableSet in Spring's GET endpoint with AngularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, guava

Having this endpoint definition:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo_resource", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public FooResponse retrieveFoo(
    @RequestParam("the_param") ImmutableSet<String> params,
    @RequestParam(name = "include_all", defaultValue = "true") boolean includeAll) {
        return aService.retrieveFoo(params, includeAll);
    }
```

I'd like to have my AngularJS controller sending the params, however, I always end-up getting the same error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet<java.lang.String>] for value '"valuez"'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate Collection type: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:43)
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:203)
at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:173)
at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:64)
at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:47)
at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.convertIfNecessary(DataBinder.java:713)
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:120)
... 111 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate Collection type: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet
at org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory.createCollection(CollectionFactory.java:206)
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToCollectionConverter.convert(StringToCollectionConverter.java:68)
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:37)
... 118 common frames omitted
```

Angular side, I have of course tried several options such as:

```
$http.get('xxx/foo_resource', {
      params: { 'the_param': JSON.stringify('valuez')}
})
```

or:

```
    $http.get('xxx/foo_resource', {
      params: { 'the_param[]': 'valuez'}
})
```

or:

```
    $http.get('xxx/foo_resource', {
      params: { 'the_param': ['valuez']}
})
```

...etc. Is this guava related? Can't I use Immutable collections for this purpose? Or am I unseeing something?

BTW, I'm using Java 8, AngularJS 1.6, Spring Boot 1.5.6, guava 22.0

Answer (score 2):

Spring not have default `ArgumentResolver`s for `ImmutableSet`. 
Parameter with `@RequestParam` anotation must have any `ArgumentResolver`s defined or default contructor.

Options:

- Use set (java.util.set) or any other coleccion.
- Create your [custom argument resolvers](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-creating-a-custom-handlermethodargumentresolver/)